# Move table from one schema to another by changing ownership oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a four tables in a schema named DEMO. I want to move/clone/copy them in another schema named TEST.

Is it posible to move the table by changing ownership from DEMO to TEST ?

I use Oracle 11 and oracle sql developer 4.

Comment: You can't move them, but you can copy/clone them. Can TEST see DEMO's tables? Or are you connected to the DB as a user with DBA privileges? Are there any indexes or referential constraints involved?

Comment: @AlexPoole I have all privileges,i tried 
update SYS.ALL_ALL_TABLES  set OWNER='TEST' where TABLE_NAME='DEMO_TABLE' but i get ORA-01031: insufficient privileges even as XE

Comment: No, never update data in `SYS` tables. Or any other built-in account. You really do not want to corrupt the data dictionary.

Comment: @AlexPoole So you suggest the export/import ?

Comment: That's a good route, but SQL Developer lets you copy tables (right-click on the table in the explorer) if you have the right privs, or you can do the same thing via SQL. But how you do it depends on complexity a bit - dependencies between the tables in particular. A datapump export/import would handle all that for you.

Comment: @AlexPoole ok thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Oracle's data pump utilities to export the tables and then import them to a different schema,

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY dump_dir AS '/path/to/put/dumps';
GRANT WRITE ON DIRECTORY dump_dir TO DEMO;
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY dump_dir TO TEST;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO TEST;
```

**Export**:

```
EXPDP DEMO/DEMOPASSWORD directory=DUMP_DIR tables=DEMO.TABLE1,DEMO.TABLE2,DEMO.TABLE3,DEMO.TABLE4 dumpfile=DEMO.dmp logfile=DEMO.log
```

**Import**:

use the `remap_schema` (and, if you need to, `remap_tablespace`):

```
IMPDP TEST/TESTPASSWORD  directory=DUMP_DIR tables=DEMO.TABLE1,DEMO.TABLE2,DEMO.TABLE3,DEMO.TABLE4 remap_schema DEMO:TEST remap_tablespace=DEMO_TBS:TEST_TBS dumpfile=DEMO.dmp logfile=DEMO.log
```

If there are foreign keys in the tables you are remapping that point to other tables in the `DEMO` schema that you have not remapped then the remapping will try remapping those too and fail to create the foreign keys (since the table does not exist in the `TEST` schema) but should still import the data. Review the output of `IMPDP` to find these failures and then use, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST.TABLE1
  ADD CONSTRAINT TABLE1__COLUMN1__FK
  FOREIGN KEY ( COLUMN1 ) REFERENCES DEMO.OTHER_TABLE ( COLUMN1 );
```

To create the appropriate foreign keys.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was able to solve the problem by using sql developer.  By clicking - tools - database copy and selecting the wanted tables. This way any object can be copied between schemas. I think in the background it does similar thing to your answer export/import.

Comment: @MasterYi Just check to be sure that SQL Developer has also copied the primary/foreign keys, constraints, indexes, etc. otherwise it could just be copying the table structure and data.

Comment: Is it just me or do you see the comment section getting messed up with the answerer's name.?

Comment: What is the Difference between TABLES and INCLUDE Parameter in impdp.
Above steps can be achieved using INCLUDE Param ( importing a Single Table from a Full expdp backup ).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the old schema from the new one, you can use:

`CREATE table_name UNRECOVERABLE AS SELECT * FROM sourceSchema.SOURCE_table;`

This will recreate the table under the new schema; and then you can drop the table from the old schema if you wish.

Comment: Will it effectively `clone` the source table's indexes and constraints as well?

Comment: No, you will have to do that separately. It's easy enough to generate the DDL to recreate those though, if you need them - e.g. `SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('INDEX', index_name)
  FROM user_indexes
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'OLD_TABLE_NAME';`

Comment: Thanks, coming from PG where there is a `create table A like B` ... this is way too complicated.